# Why is this Process running twice?

Tags: sql-server, powershell

i have a script that processes some cubes in a table, and when i run it individually, as in directly, it processes as expected a cube ONCE. however, when I am calling it through this batch file loop command, it for some reason duplicates the processing?

here is the regular Process script:

```
Invoke-ASCmd –InputFile $JSON_file -Server $Destination_Server >$process_output
```

> Scripts>runPowerShell.bat Process.ps1 CUBE

[image: Process directly]

and here is an advanced method im using for other purposes but still aim to achieve the same result:

```
$Table = Query "SELECT * from [dbo].[$cubeTable] WHERE [application] = '$App_input' ORDER BY [sequence]"
    $i=0
$CUBE = @()

foreach($row in $Table)
{   
    Write-host "`r`n---------------------------START of Script-----------------------------"
    write-host "`r`n [Application] :  $App_input"
    write-host " [Script]      :  $Script"
    $i++
    $CUBE += $row.Item("cube_name")
    #write-host " > CUBE $($i): $($CUBE[-1])`n"
    cmd /c "runPowerShell.bat $Script $($CUBE[-1])" #where $Script is Process.ps1 script that processes on each CUBE selected from table in order
}
```

That standalone script is called `scriptWrapper.ps1` which mainly loops to run this command to process multiple cubes instead of me having to specify a command for each cube i have in a table. it is called through this batch file:

```
Powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File %psFile% %2 %3 %4 %5
```

so when i run it this way:

```
Scripts>runPowerShell.bat scriptWrapper.ps1 CUBES_CATEGORY Proc.ps1
```

it Processes the same cube twice:

[image: Twice processed]

I am pretty sure something is up in the scriptWrapper.ps1 loop, but i cant point it out...

Comment: Use a debugger like ISE, and see why `foreach($row in $Table)` has more than 1 row in the table.

Comment: Why are you launching a cmd script from a powershell script to launch another powershell script?

Comment: @jwdonahue I have to because I am automating a batch of ps1 script on autosys. Autosys requires bat file call ps1 file. So the ps1 file is the wrapper which will call the batch file again to run the process ps1

Comment: So far you've said `Autosys => batch file`, and `PS1 => batch file => PS1`.  Which is it? How exactly does autosys figure into your rats nest of script files?

Comment: @jwdonahue ok so the ultimate goal is to avhieve the following: a command on Autosys (automation software) that says: runPowershell.bat scriptWrapper.ps1 CUBE_CATEGORY process.ps1. I mentioned autosys because you asked me why I'm calling a batch that calls a ps1 that calls the batch again to call process.ps1. But autosys is not the issue here nor is the batch->powershell.ps1->batch->process.ps1 command. The problem is why is it processing TWICE, which is something wrong in the loop that I cant point out

Comment: `$CUBE += ` < Why are you _appending_ to `$CUBE` within your loop?

Comment: @gvee I based this loop on the loop I have in the process script, in the process script, I append the $Server to be processed on the same way, and it works as can be seen, so I simply used the same technique in this other scrip, the scriptWrapper.ps1 loop...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Basically `$Table` was storing all rows regardless if the cube is repeating n times. it didnt take into account redundancy.

I simply had to modify my query statement in $Table:

```
$Table = Query "SELECT DISTINCT[cube_name], [sequence] from [dbo].[$cubeTable] WHERE [application] = '$App_input' ORDER BY [sequence]"
```

It now just stores one distinct cube and so the `cmd /c "runPowerShell.bat $Script $($CUBE)"` runs just that cube once